# Can I link a local dir to a dir in a remote git repo?

Tags: git

We had an old Visual SourceSafe instance at work that was recently converted to a git repo via VSS2Git.  I'm a total newbie to git.

With VSS, I could link a dir on my local machine (say, "c:\dev\perl") to any dir in VSS (say, "CompanyName/Division1/dev/source/Perl").  ie, the full local path did not have to match the full remote repo path.  I didn't need to have the full repo (with all of its other dirs that are irrelevant to me) on my local machine.

Can I do the same with git?  Or would I have to clone the entire repo locally?

Comment: There's various provisions like shallow clones and sparse checkouts but in general you clone the whole repository because you need the whole *project*. As a "total newbie to git" I would advice you to not be too fancy in your setup to begin with, and instead look into such advanced features when you've got more git time under your belt.

Comment: Why are all those other directories irrelevant to you?

Comment: You will need to unlearn many things from Visual SourceSafe as you transition to Git, and there are many terms that have very different meanings. It may be likely that a different repository layout is better for Git.

Comment: My guess is that you've converted your entire visual sourcesafe database into one big honking git repository, containing many disparate projects. This is unwise unless they have *something* in common, and even then it may be that a completely different way of handling these common parts is warranted. In general you should strive to have one repository per project.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen You are correct, the entire VSS database, which contained MANY different projects, was converted into a single git repo.  Guess I'll need to go back and redo the VSS2Git process and try to break-out the key projects into individual git repos (ugh).  Post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Monorepos do have some advantages, and I wish the Git tooling for them were better. That said, it’s likely that project repos are the right thing here.